# How do I test viewmodels with livedata?

Tags: android, testing, viewmodel

Help needed , First of all i've searched the net but haven't fallen on a post to address my needs

I have  `ViewModel` class, I have  `Fragment` that uses the `ViewModel` class via the `ViewModelProvider`, The `ViewModel` class has inputtext mutable livedata and list livedata

How to i use `Mockito` to test my UI using the `Viewmodel` using the following example.

E.g A todo app example found here https://dukescript.com/best/practices/2015/02/16/tdd-with-dukescript.html

```
TodoListViewModel model = new TodoListViewModel();
assertEquals(model.getTodos().size(), 0);
model.setInputText("bu");
model.addTodo();
assertEquals(model.getTodos().size(), 0);
model.setInputText("buy milk");
model.addTodo();
assertEquals(model.getTodos().size(), 1);
assertEquals("", model.getInputText());
```

Comment: You should go with Data driven unit testing to test Live Data saved in one of  these file extensions ( .xml , .csv , xls)

Answer (score 0):

When using view models, the GUI has observers that observe for changes in the view model's livedata so the observers are mocked and their behaviors verified such that the right calls are made to update the UI.